# Describe sample space and reasonable random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

A couple plans to continue having children until they have a girl or until they six children, whichever comes first.

I think the sample space is simply the amount of boys they can have from 0 to 5 (0 implying the first child is a girl and 5 implying the last child is a girl). Could someone please confirm this?

What I don't know how to describe is the random variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to appeal to the abstractness of defining a sample space here. Let $X_n$ be independent random variables with $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ distribution, where $p$ is the probability of a child being a girl. Set $T = \inf\{n>0: X_n = 1\}$ and let $Y=T\wedge 6$. Then
$$
\mathbb P(Y=k) = \begin{cases}
(1-p)^{k-1}p,& k=1,2,3,4,5\\
(1-p)^5,& k=6
\end{cases}
$$
is the distribution of the number of children that the couple has.

Comment: Sorry, but that's the only two things I need to know, a sample space and a random variable.

Comment: Given the definition of $Y$, I'm sure you can come up with an appropriate sample space, then.